# Unable to Updated value in table in android in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
  public  void UpdatedKycId(String kycId,String OrderId) {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("kycid",kycId);
            db.update(DateEntry_Table,cv,KEY_ORDERID+"=?"+OrderId,null);
            db.close();
            Log.d("Suecss","Sucess");

        }
```

near "e2def9b80fe4e62f4d3833": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE dataentry SET kycid=? WHERE ORDERID=?56e2def9b80fe4e62f4d3833
Please tell me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
db.update(DateEntry_Table,cv,KEY_ORDERID+"=?"+OrderId,null);
```

to

```
db.update(DateEntry_Table,cv,KEY_ORDERID+"=?", new String[]{OrderId});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this

```
String where = "KEY_ORDERID=?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(OrderId)};
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, where, whereArgs);
```